# PostgreSQL, Cumulative amount with interval

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hello there i have this example dataset:

```
 employee_id | amount     |    cumulative_amount
-------------+------------+-----------------
           2 |        100 | 100
           6 |        220 | 320
           7 |         45 | 365
           8 |         50 | 415
           9 |        110 | 525
          16 |        300 | 825
          17 |        250 | 1075
          18 |        200 | 1275
```

And interval, let's say 300:
I'd like to pick only rows, that match the interval, with condition:

Pick value if it's >= previous value+interval
(e.g if start Val = 100, next matching row is where cumulative amount >= 400, and so on)
:

```
   employee_id | amount     |    cumulative_amount
  -------------+------------+-----------------
             2 |        100 | 100 <-- $Start
             6 |        220 | 320 - 400
             7 |         45 | 365 - 400
             8 |         50 | 415 <-- 1
             9 |        110 | 525 - 715 (prev value (415)+300)
            16 |        300 | 825 <-- 2
            17 |        250 | 1075 - 1125 (825+300)
            18 |        200 | 1275 <-- 3
```

so final result would be :

```
           employee_id | amount     |    cumulative_amount
          -------------+------------+-----------------
                     2 |        100 | 100 
                     8 |         50 | 415 
                    16 |        300 | 825 
                    18 |        200 | 1275
```

How to achieve this in PostgreSQL in most efficient way ?

Column cumulative_amount is progressive sum of column amount
and it's calculated in another query, which result is dataset above, table is ordered by employee_id.

Regards.

Comment: does employee_id specify the ordering in the table?

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala : yes, it does

Comment: just noticed that folowing the logic min closet to threshold of +300 I get different last row - you sure about your sample? :) O I just am wrong about the logic?..

Comment: @VaoTsun : prev value is 825, 825+300 =1125, first row >= 1125 is 1275

Comment: ah - so 300 step is not fixed - it's more a recursive plus to last cumulative sum?..

Comment: @VaoTsun : that's exactly correct :)

Answer (score 0):

not saying it is the most effective way, but probably the easiest:

```
s=# create table s1(a int, b int, c int);
CREATE TABLE
Time: 10.262 ms
s=# copy s1 from stdin delimiter '|';
...
s=# with g as (select generate_series(100,1300,300) s)
, o as (select *,sum(b) over (order by a) from s1)
, c as (select *, min(sum) over (partition by g.s)
from o
join g on sum >= g.s and sum < g.s + 300
)
select a,b,sum from c
where sum = min
;
 a  |  b  | sum
----+-----+------
  2 | 100 |  100
  8 |  50 |  415
 16 | 300 |  825
 17 | 250 | 1075
(4 rows)
```

here I used `order by a` as you sad your cumulative sum is by first column (which reconciled with third row)